# Service Messaging is not available in FCM Next js

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement FCM (v9) in a Next js app and when I try to configure the firebase file, this error is occuring.

Error:
[Service messaging is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taV1i.png)

`Firebase.js:`

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = getMessaging(app);
```

I've seen some cases that recommend downgrading firebase to version 8 but I'd like to know if there's any way to use FCM in version 9